# Inner class vs separate classes for Java chess program design

Tags: java, this, inner-classes

The way I wrote my Chess program in Java, there's a GameLauncher class and a Game class which contains all the other classes because all those classes need access to Game's instance variable `private Piece[][] board` representing the Pieces on the board. These inner classes are Player, BoardPanel (a JPanel), Piece, and all the other piece subclasses (Rook, Horse, Bishop, King, etc.).

I'm wondering if the standard way to implement this is to have the classes as inner classes of Game (thereby allowing them to access Game's `board` object directly) or have them as separate classes and pass `this` to every single call of `new`?

That is,

```
board[0][0] = new Car(new Point(0, 0), RED);
```

compared to

```
board[0][0] = new Car(new Point(0, 0), RED, this);
```

Comment: Usually a inner class is used when the inner class must modify attributes of the outer class, in other case, i think has no reason

Comment: I suggest separate class, and for communication I don't agree to pass `this`, you would have an interface that contains everything needs to be done by the board, this grands you to control of calling to board class to

Comment: Assuming that this is a normal version of chess there would only be one Board and one Game.

So you could have a static instance of each and a static method called  .getInstance()

then you can access anything from any class.  Just a thought.

Comment: @DGomez: If they are passing `this`, then that implies that the `Car` class needs to access the outer instance

Answer (score 0):

You would create the other classes as separate classes. Each of the other classes could simply contain an instance of Game, as you said in your question. It seems fine to me. However, since `board` is private, you would want to make a `public Piece[][] getBoard()` method in `Game` so that the other classes can access the board.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way to do this, although I guess people out there would define classes separately. Having an Inner class is logically completely fine ! But there are few ways to handle separate class definition.

1. Singleton / Factory class approach - have a static method in a factory class distributed current board everytime it is needed. Of course you would need to create wrapping class for your array - a Board class. *But this is kind of lame - just a personal opinion. I do not share the vision of programming the easy way at all cost.*
2. Have your Game class instantiate your Board class (wrapper for your array with all the methods necessary). Then pass reference to this instance of Board to the other objects in constructor and make these objects remember this board instance. This way, passing the reference is done only once at the very beginning of your program.